# Folder permissions keep changing from www-data to root

Tags: permissions

A folder under the directory /var/www/xml keeps changing permission from www-data to root meaning that no php file is able to write into the folder.

This seems to happen when I restart the server.

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root www-data 4096 Sep 10 13:40 xml

chown www-data -R /var/www/xml

drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 10 13:40 xml
```

How do I make sure this does not happen?

Answer (score 1):

**you can change the owner of the www folder it will solve it**

```
 sudo chown user /var/www
```

and logout and login.

           Then open the var folder,   right click on www folder select properties 
              now you can edit the permission of the www folder.